# Change specific part of image path

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have got this image path in my WordPress installation:

```
baseurl.com/images/02D371FEEA23-150x320px.png
```

I want to change the `150x320px` value to something like this:

```
baseurl.com/images/02D371FEEA23-800x600px.png
```

Note: the `150x320px` can be dynamic!

How can I change that part, while leaving the rest unharmed, in the best practice possible?

Comment: `url = url.replace('150x320px', '800x600px')`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the 150x320px part can be dynamic

Comment: oh i see, it has to be dynamic. Then the solution is still the one that @Satpal mentioned. Just put the second part in the replace in a variable

Comment: is the url structure always the same (i.e. it will always have a '-' and then the width/height)?

Comment: using Regex it must be accurate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming URL structure is always the same, use regex `/-\d+x\d+px\./` to replace required string.

```js
function replaceText() {
  var value = document.getElementById('inp').value;
  alert(
    value.replace(/-\d+x\d+px\./, '-800x600px.')
  );
  }

replaceText();
```

```html
<input type="text" value="baseurl.com/images/02D371FEEA23-150x320px.png" onChange="replaceText()" id="inp"/>
```

Comment: Ah, that will work just fine! I was thinking of splitting the whole string, and then picking out the right part, but that didn't seem like best practice. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>

var str = 'DSCN0551-130x130.jpg';
alert(str);
var matches = str.replace(/(\d+)x(\d+)\.(\w+)$/,"800px X 750px");
alert(matches);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex and get it done.

Below is an example.

```js
var string =  "baseurl.com/images/02D371FEEA23-150x320px.png";

var changedString = string.replace(/(-)\d+x\d+/g,"$1800x600");

console.log(changedString);
```

Explaining the Regex:
**(-)\d+x\d+**

- **(-)** : start from the hyphen, and the `(` `)` are to capture this part of the string for later use during replace.
- **\d+x\d+** : `\d` digit `+` any number followed by a `x` followed by a digit `\d` any number `+`.

During replace I make sure the captured hyphen is retained. The captured string is stored in `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about "best practice," but this should work for almost any url, including urls with dashes:

```js
function replaceImgUrl(original,newWidth,newHeight){
    //These 2 lines allow other parts of the url to have a dash
    //Divide url
    var oldDimensions = original.split("/");
    //Get last part
    oldDimensions = oldDimensions[oldDimensions.length-1];
    //Get old dimensions
    oldDimensions = oldDimensions.split("-")[1];
    oldDimensions = oldDimensions.split("px")[0];
    oldDimensions = oldDimensions.split("x");
    //oldDimensions has been figured out!
    var ret = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < original.split("/").length-1; i++)
        {
            ret += original.split("/")[i];
            ret += "/";
        }
    return ret+original.split("/")[original.split("/").length-1].replace(oldDimensions[0],newWidth).replace(oldDimensions[1],newHeight);
}

console.log(replaceImgUrl("baseurl.com/images/02D371FEEA23-150x320px.png",546,23789));
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of splitting too, picking out the parts, but I got a better way now :)

Comment: Great! Good luck with your WordPress Application.